# Showing error or success message on same page

Tags: html, spring, parameters, thymeleaf

this is my first time posting here since I couldn't figure the issue out, please keep in mind im fairly new to Spring and not that good at Java and coding in general.

I'm trying to program a Server application with Java Spring where you're able to create different accounts with specific roles. I want my users to be able to see a success or error message on the same page if the creation of an account succeded or failed.

Right now I'm using the error.param th:if tag from https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/
the specific code in my HTML file is:

```html
<div id="error" th:if="${param.error}">
        Benutzername existiert bereits.
</div>
<div id="success" th:if="${param.success}">
        Das Konto wurde erfolgreich erstellt.
</div>
```

Which works when I manually put ?success or ?error behind my URL.

I map my POST to the database by this method:

```
@PostMapping("/create/lieferant/fahrer")
public String submitDriver(@ModelAttribute Driver driver){
    if(userRepository.existsByUsername(driver.getUsername())){
        return "create/lieferant/fahrer?error";
    }
    Driver d = new Driver();
    User n = new User();
    Role r = new Role();
    d.setName(driver.getName());
    d.setTelnum(driver.getTelnum());
    d.setUsername(driver.getUsername());
    n.setUsername(driver.getUsername());
    n.setPassword(encoder().encode(driver.getPassword()));
    r.setUsername(driver.getUsername());
    r.setAuthority("LIEFERANT");
    userRepository.save(n);
    driverRepository.save(d);
    roleRepository.save(r);
    return "create/lieferant/fahrer?success";
}
```

The idea is to check if the username is already registered and if so, returning the create/lieferant/fahrer?error but it says

> Error resolving template "create/lieferant/fahrer?error", template
>   might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured
>   Template Resolvers

and the same for ?success.

What I don't understand is: it's working for the login which I've gotten from the Spring getting started guide and it seems to be working without any heavy configurations or so. Atleast I don't see any.

I'd be glad if anyone could help me figuring my issue out.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
@PostMapping("/create/lieferant/fahrer")
public ModelAndView submitDriver(@ModelAttribute Driver driver){
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.setViewName("create/lieferant/fahrer");
    try {
        if(userRepository.existsByUsername(driver.getUsername())){
            return "create/lieferant/fahrer?error";
        }
        Driver d = new Driver();
        User n = new User();
        Role r = new Role();
        d.setName(driver.getName());
        d.setTelnum(driver.getTelnum());
        d.setUsername(driver.getUsername());
        n.setUsername(driver.getUsername());
        n.setPassword(encoder().encode(driver.getPassword()));
        r.setUsername(driver.getUsername());
        r.setAuthority("LIEFERANT");
        userRepository.save(n);
        driverRepository.save(d);
        roleRepository.save(r);
        mav.addObject("success", "All was ok");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        mav.addObject("error", "Error message to change");
    }

    return "create/lieferant/fahrer?success";
}
```

You could retrieve messages on page with the two keys "success" and "error"

Comment: I can't return a String to a ModelAndView object though.

Comment: Okay, I simply changed the return to return mav; and it seems to work now, what a simple solution to a problem that took me so long! Thank you very much.